Pytorch import stuck on torch_version
I am currently starting to do basic Machine Learning via Pytorch on Linux Mint. However, I have this very weird issue. I have some imports, normally they only take at most 10s to run, and I can go on doing my things. However, today, I run the exact same code, and now, importing suddenly becomes a massive problem, as this code to import torch, suddenly went from taking some time to literally eternity:

import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)


I run this code in a venv, and I installed with it a bunch of other packages:
Package                   Version
------------------------- --------------
aiohappyeyeballs          2.4.3
aiohttp                   3.10.8
aiosignal                 1.3.1
anyio                     4.6.0
argon2-cffi               23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0
arrow                     1.3.0
asttokens                 2.4.1
async-lru                 2.0.4
attrs                     24.2.0
autograd                  1.7.0
autograd-gamma            0.5.0
babel                     2.16.0
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3
bleach                    6.1.0
certifi                   2024.8.30
cffi                      1.17.1
charset-normalizer        3.3.2
comm                      0.2.2
contourpy                 1.3.0
cycler                    0.12.1
debugpy                   1.8.6
decorator                 5.1.1
defusedxml                0.7.1
executing                 2.1.0
fastjsonschema            2.20.0
filelock                  3.16.1
fonttools                 4.54.1
formulaic                 1.0.2
fqdn                      1.5.1
frozenlist                1.4.1
fsspec                    2024.9.0
h11                       0.14.0
httpcore                  1.0.6
httpx                     0.27.2
idna                      3.10
interface-meta            1.3.0
ipykernel                 6.29.5
ipython                   8.28.0
ipywidgets                8.1.5
ISLP                      0.4.0
isoduration               20.11.0
jedi                      0.19.1
Jinja2                    3.1.4
joblib                    1.4.2
json5                     0.9.25
jsonpointer               3.0.0
jsonschema                4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1
jupyter                   1.1.1
jupyter_client            8.6.3
jupyter-console           6.6.3
jupyter_core              5.7.2
jupyter-events            0.10.0
jupyter-lsp               2.2.5
jupyter_server            2.14.2
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.3
jupyterlab                4.2.5
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0
jupyterlab_server         2.27.3
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.13
kiwisolver                1.4.7
lifelines                 0.29.0
lightning-utilities       0.11.7
lxml                      5.3.0
MarkupSafe                2.1.5
matplotlib                3.9.2
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7
mistune                   3.0.2
mpmath                    1.3.0
multidict                 6.1.0
nbclient                  0.10.0
nbconvert                 7.16.4
nbformat                  5.10.4
nest-asyncio              1.6.0
networkx                  3.3
notebook                  7.2.2
notebook_shim             0.2.4
numpy                     1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu12        12.1.3.1
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu12         9.1.0.70
nvidia-cufft-cu12         11.0.2.54
nvidia-curand-cu12        10.3.2.106
nvidia-cusolver-cu12      11.4.5.107
nvidia-cusparse-cu12      12.1.0.106
nvidia-nccl-cu12          2.20.5
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12     12.6.77
nvidia-nvtx-cu12          12.1.105
overrides                 7.7.0
packaging                 24.1
pandas                    2.2.3
pandocfilters             1.5.1
parso                     0.8.4
patsy                     0.5.6
pexpect                   4.9.0
pillow                    10.4.0
pip                       24.0
platformdirs              4.3.6
progressbar2              4.5.0
prometheus_client         0.21.0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.48
psutil                    6.0.0
ptyprocess                0.7.0
pure_eval                 0.2.3
pycparser                 2.22
pygam                     0.9.1
Pygments                  2.18.0
pyparsing                 3.1.4
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0
python-json-logger        2.0.7
python-utils              3.9.0
pytorch-lightning         2.4.0
pytz                      2024.2
PyYAML                    6.0.2
pyzmq                     26.2.0
referencing               0.35.1
requests                  2.32.3
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1
rpds-py                   0.20.0
scikit-learn              1.5.2
scipy                     1.11.4
Send2Trash                1.8.3
setuptools                75.1.0
six                       1.16.0
sniffio                   1.3.1
soupsieve                 2.6
stack-data                0.6.3
statsmodels               0.14.3
sympy                     1.13.3
terminado                 0.18.1
threadpoolctl             3.5.0
tinycss2                  1.3.0
torch                     2.4.1+cpu
torchaudio                2.4.1+cpu
torchinfo                 1.8.0
torchmetrics              1.4.2
torchvision               0.19.1+cpu
tornado                   6.4.1
tqdm                      4.66.5
traitlets                 5.14.3
triton                    3.0.0
types-python-dateutil     2.9.0.20241003
typing_extensions         4.12.2
tzdata                    2024.2
uri-template              1.3.0
urllib3                   2.2.3
wcwidth                   0.2.13
webcolors                 24.8.0
webencodings              0.5.1
websocket-client          1.8.0
widgetsnbextension        4.0.13
wrapt                     1.16.0
yarl                      1.13.1

I decided to investigate and run python -v -c "import torch", and I noted that it gets stuck on this line:
import 'torch.torch_version' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7ec23812f470>
This happened when I ran the code inside a Jupyter Notebook on VSCode, so I tried restarting the kernel, reloading VSCode, and even running the file outside (by taking that import torch code above and paste it to another file, with again forever running time), and alternative kernels doesn't work either. What should I do?
Update 1: I tried an older version of torch, namely torch==2.3.1. However it still locks in the exact same place
My Python version is 3.12.3, for anyone interested.
Update 2: I have wrote this as an github issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/137260

Would you mind running a simple python program which only includes import torch and press ctrl+c while it stuck and share the output here?It will show the stacktrace for which specific statement blocked the whole application.

Python version is highly interested. You should show your GPU spec too, depending on GPU, CUDA, cuDNN version changes and python, torch version should be changed python 3.12.X is not recommended for normal users. If you are not using gpu, install torch-cpu. try pip cache purge too

@AmadeuszLiu I attached a GitHub issue link at the end of this post, and in it I posted the full log when I try to run python -v -c "import torch"

@NoYeah I see, why is it not recommended then? Is there an issue or something.?Sagemath is a project I believe is also not working with Python 3.12 as well.

You need to check which function call is actually blocking the program for further investigation. Also please check your github issue page for troubleshooting.

@AmadeuszLiu the culprit seems to be the <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7357b6f09d00>

I was unable to reproduce the issue.According  to currently available information the import stuck at torch.torch_version.Has there been any software update on your system before the issue occured,and if this can be reproduced on any other machine？
